# oauth 2.0, JWT, Spring security, Micro services

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt, microservices

I need some understanding on over all flow of spring security.

1. I have implemented oauth2 Authorization Server and a Resource server in the same Spring Boot App.Where i am able to generate JWT tokens. And sample Rest api in this app is secured and accessible only with token.
2. I have another spring boot app which should be secured? What should i do in this. Also i need to read the token in this service to know the role of user.

Please clarify me how to implement the step2.

Comment: My recommendation is to have an Authorization service as a common service, so that all other MicroServices required JWT can use it. Your client can directly call this authorization server to get a JWT and your service 1 and service 2 can verify jwt from Authorization server.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a module where your spring security config is implemented.

In this module is the class that is annotated with the `@EnableWebSecurity` annotation, where you define the open routes. I guess you already have a class like this for your sample rest API, mentioned in step 1.

Now every microseconds that has to be secured uses this module by importing it, eg as maven dependency. By this it's api is automatically secured via spring security.

Your auth service serves a jwk endpoint where every microservice can verify a token via public key.